# Should one react on wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I upload a simple question (not for me simple, but for some people here) a lot of people start running to be the first to answer the question.

Sometimes, however, they answer wrongly (mostly because they read too fast and miss the question, all for some extra points it seems), while others answer correct. Should I write "No, this is not what I wanted, see Blabla's answer" or should I just let it be and never look at those answers again?

Comment: Down vote, that's what it's for.

Comment: A polite explanation of why it's not correct/applicable is always good. Just avoid getting dragged into an argument. Keep it neutral in tone and assume the best of any answer's intent to help. And pointing out where another answer is correct is also good. Not just for the answerer, but future readers, too.

Comment: @Ben: Yea, I guess so. But it feels so harsh to downvote someone who thinks he did it right. Ah well, thanks for the input!

Comment: A downvote is not a punishment. It is a signal to other readers as to the value of the post. If an answer is wrong, it _should_ be downvoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What @Andrew Barber says in the comments: a polite explanation is always good.

You're not obliged to comment on these answers. But if you don't tell the user that their answer didn't help you, they'll never know.

It's often a case of "Fastest Gun in the West": people want to be the first to answer, because that's a good way to get the first upvotes. Then their answer stays on top, which attracts even more upvotes.

A polite comment can break this circle.

If they won't listen to your comment, you have every reason to downvote. Then leave it at that - you've explained what's wrong, you've given the downvote, if they still won't listen, it's their problem.  It's one of the other answers, one of the answers that *did* help you, that will get your "accept", and with it the top position in the answers and a nice +15 rep.

On closing, do consider the other side of the story: maybe these answers are right, or maybe your question was unclear or ambiguous. It may be necessary to edit your own question, to clear up misunderstandings.