# How to react to unelaborated / hastily written / stupid answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

When writing a question, I am paying attention to describe what I want to achieve, I provide code and I share what I found on Google and why I can't use it.

Still, very frequently I am getting answers from which it is obvious, that my question hasn't even been read, e.g. I am asked for the code, I am offered solution I had described and can't use, or I get completely unrelated answer.

I respond with comments where I write "my code has been provided, see above", "this is not what I need", etc., and eventually we'll get to the state, where the answerers have read the question and reply that they don't know the answer. But it takes an hour of my life. Moreover, the question is cluttered with (useless) comments and answers which may discourage other people from dealing with it.

Is there a way to avoid this?

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271446/should-one-react-on-wrong-answers) and I don't have high hopes, there actually is some solution.

Example of recent question like this is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015192/how-to-set-element-width-to-100-of-page-not-browser-window-scrolling-issue).

Comment: It's not very nice to tell people trying to help you their answer is stupid.

Comment: You should always share the relevant code in the post to preserve it for future visitors to SO. If jsfiddle somehow becomes unavailable your post, sans code, becomes less clear.

Comment: Just downvote them and move on. If someone can't answer your question they can't answer your question, there's really no way to stop them from *trying* to. And you wouldn't really want that, anyways. I am guessing if this happens to you frequently that your questions may be a bit unclear, though.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree. That's why I never did that. Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @Erlik: Your title combined with an example answer that is considered bad does sound so.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I probably should've been more specific then. I considered the answers/comments in the linked question to be rather in the category "hastily written". But this question was aimed to be more general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, keep in mind that people providing answers are volunteers who are just trying to help. They always should be treated politely and with respect.

If an answer is wrong or of low quality, feel free to downvote and leave a constructive comment as to what was wrong with the answer or what they might have missed in your question. Again, be polite and focus on the technical issues with their answer. You'd be surprised at how often this can lead to answers being improved.

If you keep receiving answers that miss the point of your questions, that might be a signal that your questions aren't as clear as you think they are. You might need to refine your minimal examples for your problems, or do a better job of highlighting what you believe to be the core issue. Sometimes, this means removing unnecessary detail to get at the heart of the problem, or providing better organization to your questions.

Comment: Although I agree there are many kind people doing their best to help, my experience shows there are also quite many reputation hunters whose goal is to get reputation rather than help (not having anyone specific in mind now). My question was aimed towards answers of these people. But apart from this part I agree with the answer and thanks for that :)